# Jensen's inequality for integral without l.s.c. assumption

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I start with the following lemma

> **Lemma 1.**(Fundamental inclusion for convex sets) Let $C$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, $C$ is convex if and only if
>   \begin{equation*} \int_\Omega f\;d\mu \in C \end{equation*} for all
>   measures spaces $(\Omega,\mu)$ with $\mu(\Omega) = 1$ and all
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued integrable functions $f$ on $\Omega$ satisfying
>   $f(x)\in C$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in\Omega$.

A proof can be given based on Hahn-Banach theorem (strictly separable):

> **Proof:** Assume the latter condition holds, we show that $C$ is convex. Let $x,y\in C$ and $\lambda\in (0,1)$, we consider $\Omega =
>  \{0,1\}$ with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra, $\mu$ be the discrete
>    measure $\mu(\{0\}) = \lambda$ and $\mu(\{1\}) = 1-\lambda$, and
>    $f:\Omega\longrightarrow C$ defined by $f(0) = x$ and $f(1) = y$, then
>    clearly $\int_\Omega f\;d\mu = \lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y \in C$ and
>    therfore $C$ is convex. Conversely, if $C$ is convex, we prove by
>    contradiction. Assume that there exists $(\Omega,\mu)$ and $f$ as
>    above but \begin{equation*} x_0 = \int_\Omega f\;d\mu \notin C.
>  \end{equation*} Using Hahn-Banach theorem\footnote{In $\mathbb{R}^n$
>    then every two nonempty disjoint convex sets are separable by a closed
>    hyperplane.}, there exists $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha\in
>  \mathbb{R}$ such that \begin{equation*} \xi\cdot x < \alpha < \xi\cdot
>  x_0 \qquad\text{for all}\qquad x\in C. \end{equation*} But since
>    $f(z)\in C$ for $\mu$-a.e. $z\in \Omega$, we also have
>    \begin{equation*} \alpha<\xi\cdot x_0 =  \xi\cdot\left(\int_\Omega
>  f\;d\mu\right) = \int_\Omega \xi\cdot f(z)\;d\mu(z) \leq \alpha 
>  \end{equation*} which is a contradiction.

Using that lemma we can prove the Jensen inequality with the assumption $\Phi$ is lower semicontinuous as following (we need $\mathrm{epi}(\Phi)$ to be closed so that we can use strictly separation of Hahn Banach theorem)

> **Theorem** [Jensen inequality for convex l.s.c. functions] Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a probability space, i.e., $\mu(\Omega)
>  = 1$. If $f$ is a function $\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that it is $\mu$-integrable and if $\Phi$ is a l.s.c. convex function
>    $\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ then \begin{equation*}
>  \Phi\left(\int_\Omega f\;d\mu\right) \leq \int_\Omega\Phi\circ
>  f\;d\mu. \end{equation*}
>
> **Proof.** Let us define $C = \mathrm{epi}\;\Phi = \{(x,\lambda)\in \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R} :\Phi(x)\leq \lambda\}$. Since $\Phi$ is
>    convex l.s.c, $C$ is a closed convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Let
>    us define  \begin{equation*}
>  \mathcal{F}:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}
>  \qquad\text{by}\qquad \mathcal{F}(z) = \big(f(z),\Phi(f(z))\big).
>  \end{equation*} It is clear that $\mathcal{F}(z)\in \mathrm{epi}\;\Phi
>  = C$ for $\mu$-a.e. $z\in \Omega$, hence by Lemma 1 we deduce that  \begin{equation*} \int_\Omega \mathcal{F}(z)\;dz =
>  \left(\int_\Omega f\;d\mu, \int_\Omega \Phi\circ f\;\mu\right) \in
>  \mathrm{epi}\;\Phi \end{equation*} which gives us our desired claim.

My question is,

We have a version of Hahn Banach theorem saying that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, any two nonempty disjoint convex sets can be separated by a closed hyperplane (not strictly seperated). Can we use that to relax the condition $\Phi$ is lower semicontinuous in Lemma 1 so that we can generalize Jensen inquality without l.s.c. assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\Phi\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function, then it is continuous.

You can have problems if $\Phi$ is extended-valued.

Comment: It is not correct, it is only correct for $\mathbb{R}^1$.

Comment: $\Phi$ is locally Lipschitz continuous in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Can you give a reference? I don't think it is true in dimension bigger than 1.

Comment: You can check on a book of convex analysis (e.g. Rockafellar) or here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216778/continuity-of-a-convex-function

Comment: In fact, it is locally Lipschitz continuous and hence differentiable ae.

Comment: @Sean Any real valued convex function is locally Lipschitz continuous on any open set (in $\mathbb{R}^n$), hence by the Rademacher theorem it is differentiable ae. (in fact, there are must stronger continuity properties, but not relevant here). So, unless the author was considering extended valued functionals, the lsc. assumption is superflous.