# If $x^*$ is an optimal solution of $P$, then it is an optimal solution of the problem $Q$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $P$ be the problem
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\text{min} \ \  && f(\mathbf{x})\\
&s.t && g(x) \leq 0\\
& &&x\in X
\end{alignat}
for convex functions $f$ and $g$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set. Then if $\mathbf{x}^*$ is an optimal solution to $P$ with $g(x)<0$, then $\mathbf{x}^*$ is also an optimal solution to the problem $Q$:
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\text{min} \ \  && f(\mathbf{x})\\
& &&x\in X.
\end{alignat}

I'm having trouble seeing how exactly $x^*$ would be an optimal solution to $Q$. Is there a way to exploit $g$ and its convexity to show this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let $h_P(x) = f(x)$ over $g(x) \le 0$ and $x \in X$ and prolongate it with $+\infty$ otherwise, and $h_Q(x)=f(x)$ over $x \in X$. Then $P$ and $Q$ can be rewritten as $$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} h_P(x)$$ 
and 
$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} h_Q(x).$$

By optimality condition on convex problems using subgradients, we know that $x^*$ is an optimal solution of $P$ iff the subgradient of $h_P$ at $x^*$ contains $0$.

The set $\{x \in X,g(x)<0\}$ is open in $X$ since $g$ is continuous. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216778/continuity-of-a-convex-function)  for details.

If $x^*$ satifies $g(x^*) <0$, either $x^*$ lies in the interior of $X$ and $h_P=h_Q$ on an open set around $x^*$ and the subgradient of $h_P$ at $x^*$ is the same as the subgradient of $h_Q$. Or $x^*$ lies in the boundary of $X$ and $h_P=f=h_Q$ also around it since $g$ does not interfere, and we can make the same conclusion on subgradients.

Since $x^*$ is an optimal solution to $P$, the subgradient of $h_P$ at $x^*$ contains $0$. Hence, the subgradient of $h_Q$ at $x^*$ also contains $0$ and by optimality condition aforementionned, $x^*$ is a solution to $Q$.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to write the added condition, that $g(x)<0$

Comment: It should be fine now. I messed up with some details.

Comment: @nicomezi Can we say that the set of optimal solutions of $H_P(x)$ is subset of optimal solutions of $H_Q(x)$ and because $x^*$ is in the first he must be in the second and we get the same result?

Comment: I think @user722447 ment that $g(x^*)<0$ and not $g(x)<0$ for all $x$

Comment: They have the same set of solutions as $h_P$ and $h_Q$ are only different where the (equivalents) constraints are not satisfied.